# Shared Websites in Azure

Tags: azure

If there are only requests to a shared Azure website during day hours (12 hours per day) does this mean the monthly bill would be for ~375 hours? All of the calculator prices are based on 744 hours which equates to one month.

Currently the [calculator](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/) shows the pricing for one shared website is the same as one small VM so why even have the shared level at all?

**Edit**: I just found out there was actually a bug in the Azure Calculator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to pay for every hour (minute from June) your Web site, VM, Mobile service and cloud service has been online/available. This means if you keep your site running for a month, you will have to pay for ~744 hours (average hours in a month).

Microsoft changed the Azure pricing model to a charge per minute your VM is running last month (June). Previous to last month you would also have to pay for each hour even if you VM was stopped. When you stop your VM now, you will no longer be billed for each hour the VM is stopped.

In your case, this means you would have to stop and start your website to pay less per month.

As for the pricing. As far as I know the cost for one shared website is less than the other options (extra small VM, extra small CS, etc).

For example (using the calculator for 1 instance):

- Shared Website: €7,21
- Extra Small VM: €11,09